# Why does my Leetcode Reverse Integer solution does an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

For [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/) easy question, I eventually got to this code :

```
/**
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {number}
 */
var reverse = function(b) {
    let x = b;
    let result = 0;
    while(x !== 0) {
        console.log(`tomato: ${x}`)
        let digit = x % 10;
        console.log({digit});
        result = result * 10 + digit;
        console.log({result});
        x = Math.floor(x / 10)
        console.log(`potato ${x}`);
    }
    return result;
};
```

and it's running an infinite loop:

```
tomato: 123
{ digit: 3 }
{ result: 3 }
potato 12
tomato: 12
{ digit: 2 }
{ result: 32 }
potato 1
tomato: 1
{ digit: 1 }
{ result: 321 }
potato 0
tomato: -123
```

I know the answer is uncomplete, not considering negative numbers, etc,  and I got it right eventually, but in this sceneario I don't understand why potato eventually prints 0 and tomato -123 if there's no code between them and loop never ends.

Comment: consider the output of `console.log(Math.floor(-1/10))` it's not `0` is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine (for nonnegative numbers anyway).

The reason it *looks like* it's broken is that LeetCode runs all tests sequentially and concatenates the logs.

So, your code passes the first test case `123`, and after it has finished LC runs the second test case `-123`, which hangs up in an infinite loop (because it *is* negative).

To prove this, you can insert a `console.log` before the loop, to see where the new testcase begins.

---

Enabling your code to handle negative numbers is actually fairly easy: because the modulo operator in JS returns negative numbers if the dividend is negative, that part doesn't need to be changed at all!

What you do need to change is the division part: `Math.floor` rounds towards `-Infinity`, so it breaks your code for negative numbers. You can use `Math.trunc` instead, which **trunc**ates its input, rounding towards `0` in effect.

---

The question (quite annoyingly) also requires to check for overflow without using bigger integers, which means that you will have to insert a check before the multiplication.